# removing accent in letter in python, works in idle shell but not when in file in Visual Studio?

Tags: python

When i run unidecode.unidecode("32 rue d'Athènes Paris France") in the python idle shell it works, but when i run a script using exec(open(scriptnam).read()) in the idle shell with the following code it doesn't?

```
import unidecode

print(unidecode.unidecode("32 rue d'Athènes Paris France"))
```

i get:

```
32 rue d'AthA"nes Paris France
```

Answer (score 0):

Special character support depends not only on Python, but also on the console you use.

On Windows, you can configure this behaviour using the [chcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp) command.

On linux, it depends. This is a good question to look at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303712/how-can-i-enable-utf-8-support-in-the-linux-console